# Restoring npm packages using gulp

Tags: visual-studio, version-control, npm, gulp, gulp-install

I'm using Visual Studio and TypeScript to develop a Web application. There's something pretty basic I don't understand.

I don't want to check in all the node modules into my source control (it's A LOT of files and I don't want to pollute my repository with external code updates). So I want to be able to restore them before building. I found online that gulp-install can be used to restore packages. However, gulp-install is a package itself, so how can it be used?

In the gulp tutorial it said that gulp itself should be installed both globally and locally. I assume that the global installation allows running the gulp file even when the rest of the packages are not there. But what about the rest of them? gulp-install didn't mention it should be installed globally. Now, I could write a pre-build event which runs nmp install, but then all the packages would get installed, so I don't understand what gulp-install is good for...

So what I'm asking really is what is the correct and intended way to use gulp, gulp-install and source control together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know whether this is what the authors of gulp and/or gulp-install had in mind, but this is what I ended up doing:
I installed a NuGet package called [npm.js](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Npm.js/) which depends on [Node.js](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Node.js/) and runs `npm install` prior to building.
The minimal Node.js version it depends on is outdated but there's a newer Node.js package which you can install and gets you node 5.3.0. If I ever need a newer node version maybe I'll ask the author to create a new package, or do it myself.

So I ended up not using gulp-install but rather install all the node packages using NuGet.

This solution works for me because NuGet is something I don't have to install - it's always there both on the development environment and on the build servers, so the solution is entirely self-contained and doesn't depend on any new installations.

Answer (score 0):

"I could write a pre-build event which runs npm install" - this is what you want. Going to route of gulp-install does require all users would already have a global gulp install present. Having gulp install allows you to pull from other package managers in one call vs JUST pulling npm in but as you said you have to have gulp installed somewhere already for it to work right out of source control. You COULD also JUST check in the local npm gulp install if you want.